How to handle Query Builder in Symfony as a generic solution
In Symfony, we usually have some repository method that we need to apply some query filters (criteria) to filter out some properties and get the desired data. I am looking for the best practices or your code sample to pass the array of filters to the method that we are creating query builder expression without worrying about the filter implementation. If you use ApiPlatform in your Symfony project, it does the job for you with API Filters, but the problem is, it performs just in case you use  the provider interface that it does not let you have enough control to do custom queries. As a consequence, You need to handle query filters with API Platform as well as your own way
Please share your ideas and thought
        ->andWhere('f.deletedAt is NULL')
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->setParameter('paymentMode', BmpPaymentMode::INVOICE->value);

    foreach ($invoicedAmountOperations as $operation => $value) {
        if (!in_array($operation, self::QUERY_COMPARISON_FUNC, true)) {
            continue;
        }

        $expr = $queryBuilder->expr()->$operation('total_invoiced_amount', $value);              $queryBuilder->andHaving($expr);
    }

I have tried to implement a custom filter in inspiration of API Platform to convert the query string to query builder expression :
trait FilterScopeHandlerTrait { 
    public function applyFilters(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, array $filterQueryParams): void { 

    $entityFilters = $this->extractEntityFilters($queryBuilder);

    if ([] === $entityFilters) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($filterQueryParams as $property => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($property, $entityFilters)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$entityFilters[$property] instanceof SearchFilterStrategyEnum) {
            continue;
        }
        $filterImp = $entityFilters[$property]->value;

        /** @var AbstractFilterScope $filterImpConcrete */
        $filterImpConcrete = new $filterImp();
        $filterImpConcrete->apply($queryBuilder, $property, $value);
    }
}

but you need to keep both in your entity which is not nice so, I am looking for a more consistent solution
#[ApiQueryBuilderFilter([
    'id' => SearchFilterStrategyEnum::EXACT_STRATEGY,
    'name' => SearchFilterStrategyEnum::PARTIAL_STRATEGY,
    'marketingContribution' => SearchFilterStrategyEnum::RANGE_STRATEGY
])]

